# htaccess - rewrites/redirects for addon domains?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I am planning to create some addon domains through cPanel, I'm aware that their content can be accessed by visiting `addondomain.maindomain.com` and `maindomain.com/addondomain` - this could lead to duplicate content with search engines, amongst other things, so I would like to prevent this if possible.

After some research it seems the best (probably only) option would be to use .htaccess and rewrites so that the addon domain can only be accessed at www.addondomain.com - what is the best way to go about doing this and can I have the .htaccess file within the `maindomain.com` directory or will I need it for each addon domain I create?

Any help would be much appreciated, thank you :)

Comment: I wish there's a day when control panel creators learn something about web sites... *sigh*

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteRule ^addonedomain/(.*)$ http://addondomain.maindomain.com/$1
```

this code will redirect user from `maindomain.com/addonedomain` directory to `addonedomain.maindomain.com` !
it's better to put this code in `.htaccess` file in root of add-on domain!

Comment: The file should go in the main domain's root directory. Otherwise, this `RewriteRule` won't match.